# PHP - Session variables not carrying over to next page on one device, but does on another

Tags: php, session

Although this question has been asked many times, I still cannot find a solution. To clarify, I am a PHP beginner and am running everything locally with the same version XAMPP on both devices (No settings changed), and yes, I have used session_start() on all pages. I managed to get the session variables working on my PC but once I copied the same php files to my laptop (which has to be the one running it at the end of the day) and ran it from there, none of them carried over so I made 2 test files.

Here is my first file test.php:

```
<?php
  session_start();
  $_SESSION['test'] = "abc";
  $_SESSION['test2'] = "def";
  echo $_SESSION['test'];
  echo $_SESSION['test2'];
?>
<Hyperlink to test2.php>
```

Here is the code for test2.php:

```
<?php
  session_start();
  echo $_SESSION['test'];
  echo $_SESSION['test2'];
?>
```

test.php output:

```
abcdef <Hyperlink to test2.php>
```

test2.php output:

```
Notice: Unidentified index: test in C:\xampp\htdocs\test2.php on line 10
Notice: Unidentified index: test2 in C:\xampp\htdocs\test2.php on line 11
```

An isset() and print_r() shows that the session exists but is empty. 
  It be something with my laptop but I have no idea at this point. Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: clarified my question

Comment: Each Session belongs one device per user.

Comment: Question: You are running **both** pages from the same device right. I mean you launch the browser and run `test.php` and then click the link to cause `test2.php` to run from the same PC and the same Browser?

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yes

Comment: i try the same code in my local machine and it is work see if your browser allowed session variable or anything else me be the problem but not the code